# Is this a Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^{1}[0,1]$ be the space of all real valued functions on $[0,1]$ which have continuous derivatives and define the norm by;

$\|f\|:=|f(0)|+\sup\limits_{0\leq t \leq 1}|f'(t)|$

Is it a Banach space?

Comment: Integrate the uniform limit of the derivatives of a Cauchy sequence in that norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that your space is complete we will use the fact that $C[0,1]$ is complete. Consider a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)\subset C^1[0,1]$. By definition of $C^1$ this implies that $(f_n')$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$. As $C[0,1]$ is Banach there exists some $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $f_n'\to g$ in $C[0,1]$. Furthermore $(f_n(0))$ is also Cauchy, and must converge to some $f_0\in \mathbb C$, by the completeness of the field. Let us now define $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ by
$$f(t)=f_0+\int_0^tg(x)dx.$$
We claim that $f_n\to f$ in $C^1[0,1]$. This is simply because the fundamental theorem of calculus gives us
$$\|f-f_n\|=|f_n(0)-f_0|+\sup_t|f'_n(t)-g(t)|.$$
The result then follows by the nature of $g$ and $f_0$.

Comment: There are two typos, which I can't fix because it is too few characters to change. It should be $f'_n\to g$ (the prime is missing) and $|f'_n(t)-g(t)|$ (there is a $+$ instead).

Comment: @user647486 Great thanks for letting me know!